# Ubuntu crashed please help!

Tags: boot, grub2

My laptop starts until the login screen and when I put a password it freezes or shows a blue screen. It never happened before. I didn't drop my laptop or spill water on it. When I go to the grub, it doesn't show a recovery mode. My version of Ubuntu is 16.04. What should I do?

Comment: Does GRUB show two different kernel versions you can choose from? If so, try the smaller numbered one and see if that helps. If so, there's more to do to fix the problem, so reply here.